# What is a good practice when parsing program parameters in C

Tags: c, parsing, parameters

I'm parsing the parameters passed to the program. I'd like to:

1. do nothing special if there are no parameters
2. set `flag` to 1 if only `-k` is passed as an argument
3. call `ignore()` function if there where any parameters different from `-k`

Is the code below doing it properly? Can it be **imporved** to meet standards and good practice guidelines?

```
  int flag = FALSE;
  if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "-k") == 0)
    flag = TRUE;
  else if (argc >= 2)
    ignore();
```

Comment: Remove the macros, they're not useful. Consider the case when there is exactly one parameter, but it's not `-k`. Does your code do the right thing?

Comment: `getopt` is a standard way of doing this in UNIX-like systems.

Comment: There are many argument parsing libraries.  Consider `argv_parse` and `libpopt`.

Comment: Whatever you do, I strongly recommend not parsing the arguments in `main`.

Comment: Don't invent your own Boolean, C has one since 1999.

Comment: Detail: `else if (argc >= 2) ignore();` differs from "call ignore() function if there where any parameters different from -k".  Consider the case of 2 arguments both called `"-k"`.

Comment: This post is better for the site http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following program show how you can use getopt :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void ignore() {
  printf("Ignore\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if(argc <= 1) {
    printf("Do nothing\n");
    return 0;
  } else if(argc > 2) {
    ignore();
  } else {
    int c, flag;
    flag = FALSE;
    while((c = getopt (argc, argv, ":k")) != -1) {
      switch(c) {
      case 'k':
    flag = TRUE;
    break;
      default:
    ignore();
    break;
      }
    }
    printf("Flag = %d\n",flag);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: `getopt` is not in the standard C library, but comes with POSIX.